# I want to implement the nested loop as a recursive function in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, math, combinations

```
List<string> post = new List<string>();
    
for(int i0= 0; i0 < 4; i0++)
    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < 4; i1++)
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 4; i2++)
            for(int i3 = 0; i3 < 4; i3++)
                for(int i4 = 0; i4 < 4; i4++)
                    for(int i5 = 0; i5 < 4; i5++)
                    {
                        post.Add(Convert.ToString(i0) + "," + Convert.ToString(i1) + "," + Convert.ToString(i2) + "," + Convert.ToString(i3) + "," + Convert.ToString(i4) + "," + Convert.ToString(i5));
                    }
```

It would be nice to implement it simply as a recursive function, but I haven't found a great way yet.

Comment: You know what a stackoverflow exception is? why would you want to fill the stack with `4,096` methods?

Comment: You could also do it with  just one for-loop. i0 .. i5 have values 0..3 so you can see i0,i1,..i5 as a 6-digit number base 4  (so you coul count in one loot from 0 to 4^6-1) and than extract the values for i0 .. i5 from it.

Comment: I need to get the all combination.

Comment: if your goal is all combination , just use one for loop , and check that value if over 4  carry it,

Comment: You will get all the combinations if you use the nice "trick" @MrSmith42 suggested above.

Comment: @MrSmith42 - could you provide an anwer of your idea?

Comment: please explain why you need (or want) to do a recursion of your code?

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it with just one for-loop. i0 .. i5 have values 0..3 so you can see i0,i1,..i5 as a 6-digit number base 4 (so you could count in one loop from 0 to 4^6-1) and than extract the values for i0 .. i5 from it.

```
List<string> post = new List<string>();
for(int count= 0; count < 4096; count++){
  int i0=(count / 1024) % 4;  // same as "count / 1024"  // same as "count >> 10"
  int i1=(count /  256) % 4;  // same as "(count >> 8)& 3"
  int i2=(count /   64) % 4;  // same as "(count >> 6)& 3"
  int i3=(count /   16) % 4;  // same as "(count >> 4)& 3"
  int i4=(count /    4) % 4;  // same as "(count >> 2)& 3"
  int i5=(count /    1) % 4;  // same as "count % 4"   // same as "count & 3"
  post.Add(Convert.ToString(i0) + ","
         + Convert.ToString(i1) + "," 
         + Convert.ToString(i2) + "," 
         + Convert.ToString(i3) + "," 
         + Convert.ToString(i4) + "," 
         + Convert.ToString(i5));
 }
```

Remark instead of division and modulo you could also mask the wanted bits and shift them afterwards. (see comments in the code)

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, changing your iterations to recursion is **not advisable**, because it will fill your stack with 4096 call frames.

My answer below is an alternative way to do it, based on **@MrSmith42**'s comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73246546/i-want-to-implement-the-nested-loop-as-a-recursive-function-in-c-sharp#comment129358042_73246546).

**The idea:**

Since all your indices have the values **0..3**, you can see each combination of them as a number in [**base 4**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternary_numeral_system). `i0` will be the least significant digit, and `i5` will be the most significant one.

If you need 6 indices, there will be **4^6** combinations of them. There's a one-to-one match between these combinations, and the numbers **0..(4^6-1)**.

The code below demonstrates this approach.
You can also change the number of indiced by changing the constant `NUM_INDICES`, or the number of values via `NUM_VALUES`.

**Code example:**

```cs
List<string> post = new List<string>();

const int NUM_VALUES = 4;
const int NUM_INDICES = 6;

int numCobinations = (int)Math.Pow(NUM_VALUES, NUM_INDICES); // Better use an integer exponentiation. I used `Pow` to keep the code short.
int[] indices = new int[NUM_INDICES];   // will hold your indices i0..i5 but in reverse order

// Iterate over all combinations:
for (int iComb=0; iComb<numCobinations; ++iComb)
{
    // Create the values for the indices (in reverse order):
    int combination = iComb;
    for (int iIdx=0; iIdx < NUM_INDICES; ++iIdx)
    {
        indices[iIdx] = combination % NUM_VALUES;
        combination /= NUM_VALUES;
    }
    // Create the final string. Note that the indices above was created in a reverse order so we reverse again now.
    string str = "";
    for (int iIdx = NUM_INDICES-1; iIdx >= 0; --iIdx)
    {
        str += indices[iIdx].ToString();
        if (iIdx != 0) str += ",";
    }
    post.Add(str);
}

// Print the final strings:
foreach (var s in post)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

**Output:**

```
0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1
0,0,0,0,0,2
...
3,3,3,3,3,1
3,3,3,3,3,2
3,3,3,3,3,3
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function would receive the nesting level and the current values of the `i`'s (say as an array). If would either perform a for loop on the index of the current level, calling itself with the next level, or just output the `i`'s.

Pseudocode:

```
Nested(Level, I[6]):
  if Level < 6:
    for I[Level]= 0 to 3:
      Nested(Level+1, I)
  else
    Output(I)
```

Call with

```
Nested(0, I)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that a recursive solution is not the best solution. But it works.

```
var post = new List<string>();

CombineRecursively(Array.Empty<int>(), post);

static int[] CombineRecursively(int[] currentCombination, List<string> results)
{
    const int positionsCount = 6;
    const int maxNumber = 4;

    if (currentCombination.Length > 0 && currentCombination.Last() < maxNumber)
    {
        var newPositions = currentCombination.ToArray();
        newPositions[^1] += 1;
        CombineRecursively(newPositions, results);
    }

    if (currentCombination.Length < positionsCount)
    {
        return CombineRecursively(currentCombination.Append(0).ToArray(), results);
    }

    results.Add(string.Join(", ", currentCombination));

    return currentCombination;
}
```